# ffmpeg + AWS Lambda issues. Won't compress full video

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

So I followed [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/) tutorial to set everything up, and changed the function a bit to compress video, but no matter what I try, on larger videos (basically anything over 50-100MB), the output file will always be cut short, and depending on the encoding settings I'm using, will be cut by different amounts.  I tried using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848232/ffmpeg-in-an-aws-lambda-will-only-output-5-seconds-of-converted-video), adding a -nostdin flag to my ffmpeg command, but that also didn't seem to fix the issue.
Another odd thing, is no matter what I try, if I remove the '-f mpegts' flag, the output video will be 0B.
My Lambda function is set up with 3008MB of Memory (submitted a ticket to get my limit upped so I can use the full 10240MB available), and 2048MB of Ephemeral storage (I honestly am not sure if I need anything more than the minimum 512, but I upped it to try and fix the issue).  When I check my cloudwatch logs, on really large files, it will occasionally time out, but other than that, I will get no error messages, just the standard start, end, and billable time messages.

This is the code for my lambda function.

```
import json
import os
import subprocess
import shlex
import boto3

S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET = "rw-video-out"
SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT = 600

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3_source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3_source_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s3_source_key))[0]
    s3_destination_filename = s3_source_basename + "-comp.mp4"

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_source_signed_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
        Params={'Bucket': s3_source_bucket, 'Key': s3_source_key},
        ExpiresIn=SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT)

    ffmpeg_cmd = f"/opt/bin/ffmpeg -nostdin -i {s3_source_signed_url} -f mpegts libx264 -preset fast -crf 28 -c:a copy - "
    command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
    p1 = subprocess.run(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    resp = s3_client.put_object(Body=p1.stdout, Bucket=S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET, Key=s3_destination_filename)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Object(s3_source_bucket,s3_source_key).delete()

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Processing complete successfully')
    }
```

This is the code from the solution I mentioned, but when I try using this code, I get output.mp4 not found errors

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    os.chdir('/tmp')
    s3_source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    s3_source_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    s3_source_basename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s3_source_key))[0]
    s3_destination_filename = s3_source_basename + ".mp4"

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    s3_source_signed_url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
        Params={'Bucket': s3_source_bucket, 'Key': s3_source_key},
        ExpiresIn=SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT)
    print(s3_source_signed_url)
    s3_client.download_file(s3_source_bucket,s3_source_key,s3_source_key)
    # ffmpeg_cmd = "/opt/bin/ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i \"" + s3_source_signed_url + "\" output.mp4 "
    ffmpeg_cmd = f"/opt/bin/ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i {s3_source_key} output.mp4 "
    # command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
    # print(command1)
    os.system(ffmpeg_cmd)
    # os.system('ls')
    # p1 = subprocess.run(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    file = 'output.mp4'
    resp = s3_client.put_object(Body=open(file,"rb"), Bucket=S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET, Key=s3_destination_filename)
    # resp = s3_client.put_object(Body=p1.stdout, Bucket=S3_DESTINATION_BUCKET, Key=s3_destination_filename)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Object(s3_source_bucket,s3_source_key).delete()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Processing complete successfully')
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks like the solution I posted earlier actually does work, my issue was I changed the ffmpeg command to use s3_source_signed_url, instead of s3_source_key, changing it back to s3_source_key and adding the -nostdin flag appears to have fixed my issues.